# Is $[0,1]^J$ closed in $\mathbb{R}^J$ with the uniform topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $J$ be any infinite set.

If $[0,1]^J$ is closed in the uniform topology , it would prove $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is not locally compact since $[0,1]^\omega$ is not locally compact either. (and would help in the "Review of the Basics" on Munkres' Topology).

Comment: $[0,1]^J$ **is** closed in $\Bbb R^J$ with the product topology (since it is compact and $\Bbb R^J$ is Hausdorff).

Comment: And since it’s closed in the product topology, it’s closed in the uniform topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It $\textbf{is}$ closed in the uniform topology.

We will prove its closure is contained in $[0,1]^J$ itself.

If there were $x\in \mathbb{R}^J$ such that $|x_{\alpha_0}|>1$ for some $\alpha_0\in J$ then taking $\varepsilon = \min\{\frac{1-|x_\alpha|}{2},1\}$ we have $B_{\bar{\rho}}(x,\varepsilon)\cap [0,1]^J = \emptyset$.
This is because if $y\in B_{\bar{\rho}}(x,\varepsilon)$ we have $\sup(\bar{d}(x_\alpha,y_\alpha)) < \varepsilon$ so we have $|x_{\alpha_0}-y_{\alpha_0}|<\frac{1-|x_{\alpha_0}|}{2}$ so $0<|1-y_{\alpha_0}|$ and $y\not\in [0,1]^J$.